# I don't understand how absolute path works with local/remote hosts

Tags: html, css, path, localhost

I have my website project in `/home/username/project` with `index.html` in it. `index.html` has to contain the following .css file `/home/username/project/css/application.css`, so I try to load it like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/application.css"/>
```

I run index.html page on my localhost and see no changes. Browser developer tools show me that style sheet doesn't exist in `/home/username/css/application.css`. Of course, because it is in the project folder, why does host trying to find it there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify that the folder containing the css file in nested inside the folder containing your html file by putting a `.` before the path.

So your line becomes:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/application.css"/>
```

For additional info, if you want to go the folder containing the folder of your html file, you have to put `..`.
So, for example, if your css file was in `/home/username/css/application.css`, your line becomes:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/application.css"/>
```

Comment: I don't want to specify relative path, because some files than should contain something like this `../../../../css/style.css`. Besides, I use harp compiler to make web pages, so it generates application.css with the absolute path.

Comment: Then just add `/project` to your path.
So your line becomes `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/project/css/application.css"/>`

Comment: Right, I knew that way, but I hoped to see the explanation of how it works. Is it possible for me to make host search resources in the project folder? Does the path depend on the host? I'm quite lost with this stuff.

Comment: Could you precise what you mean by "host"?

Are you running your html on a local server or something?

Comment: I was running on my localhost made by WebStorm IDE and on GitHub remote host.

Comment: There is the answer. The root folder of your host is `/home/username`.

It means that the `/` in your html page leads to `/home/username` and not `/home/username/project` wich is why you had an error.

Comment: So if I decide to host my project somewhere on remote host, firstly I should find out what is their root folder to configure my absolute paths?

Comment: Of course. If you change the host or the name of a folder, you will have to change every absolute path you have. That's why relative paths are way better in your case :)